# Combining custom taxonomy posts with default posts on one archive page

Tags: archives, custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying to get custom archive posts and default posts combined onto one archive page which I have managed... sort of but I can't get pagination to work either using the pagenavi plugin or the themes default pagination code. I have tried using paged but if anything did show I'm then not sure it would page both categories together or just one.

I need to combine two categories, one a custom taxonomy, the other the default and then have them styled differently and have a set number of the combined posts on the page and to be able have them in pages of 9 posts.

code I'm using:

```
            <?php if (is_category()) { ?>
                <h1 class="page-title">
                <span><?php _e(); ?></span> <?php single_cat_title(); ?>
                </h1>
            <?php } ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive' ); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>

            <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

            <?php
            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'events',
            'posts_per_page' => '6',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'event_cat','events',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'events','upcoming-events'
            )
            )
            );?>
            <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive-events' ); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>

            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'missing' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Changed the above to:

```
                        <?php if (is_category()) { ?>

                        <h1 class="page-title">
                            <span><?php _e(); ?></span> <?php single_cat_title(); ?>
                        </h1>
                    <?php } ?>

                        <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-3">

                            <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '7' )); ?>


                            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive' ); ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>

                        <?php else : ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'missing' ); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

                 <?php

                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'events',
                'posts_per_page' => '3',
                'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
                'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'event_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'events'
                )
                )
                );?>

                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

                        <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-3">
                            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'archive-events' ); ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php if (function_exists('joints_page_navi')) { ?>
                        <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <nav class="wp-prev-next">
                            <ul class="clearfix">
                                <li class="prev-link"><?php next_posts_link(__('&laquo; Older Entries', "jointstheme")) ?></li>
                                <li class="next-link"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Entries &raquo;', "jointstheme")) ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand you here. Concern 1: a) Which is the custom taxonomy and b) which is the term assigned to this custom taxonomy. Concern 2: a) Which is the built-in category. Your tax_query is all wrong if you are trying to get posts from a custom taxonomy and a built-in category

Comment: Also, please advice on which page are you doing this

Comment: Doing this on the archive.php file. Added code to the above that now works for me but it's probably still a bit messy?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you scrap everything that you have and go back to the default loop on your archive page. Custom queries are always troublesome on archive pages.

Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the query vars before the main query is executed. This way, you won't have any unnecessary queries and problems with pagination. You are going to make use of a tax-query here to include your two terms. For all available parameters for use in `pre_get_posts`, see [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Here is my idea

- As said, return to the default loop in your archive page
- In your functions.php, add the following using `pre_get_posts` and the conditional check `is_archive()`. This code will add the two desired terms to your archive page

  ```
  function custom_archive_query( $query ) {
      if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
          $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 9 );
          $query->set( 'post_type', 'any' );
          $tax_query = array(
              'relation' => 'OR',
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'event_cat',
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => 'events',
              ),
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'category',
                  'field'    => 'term_id',
                  'terms'    => '7',
              ),
          );
           $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

      }
  }
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_archive_query' );
  ```
- As for the styling issue, on your archive page inside the loop, use the two conditionals, [`has_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) and [`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) to check to which term a post belongs, and according to that, style it

  ```
  if( has_category( 7 ) ) {
      // DO SOMETHING FOR CATEGORY
  }elseif( has_term( 'events', 'event_cat' ) ) {
      // DO SOMETHING FOR TERM event_cat
  }
  ```

*PLEASE NOTE: This is all untested*

**EDIT**

You can do the exact same thing as above using `WP_Query` as well